# why adapter can not display colors array?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-cardview

i have an  adapter and i pass array of colors and array of text > it is not display any item of the array of colors  ?

```
 public class HoursFromToAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context  context;
        private String[] mHoursRenge;
        private int[] mColors;

        private TextView mHoursRangeTxt;
        private CardView mCardView;

        public HoursFromToAdapter(Context context, String[] hoursRenge , int[] colors ) {
            this.context=context;
            this.mHoursRenge=hoursRenge;
            this.mColors=colors;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            /*return number of elements inside this array*/
            return mHoursRenge.length;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            /*return the item at posion -position-*/
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            /*return the id of the row which in this case the index of the array*/
            return 0;
        }


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.day_item,parent,false);
            View v;

            LinearLayout ln;
            if(convertView == null) {
               v = new View(context);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.day_item, null);
                ln=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.card_containner);

                mHoursRangeTxt= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_hours_from_to);
                mHoursRangeTxt.setText(mHoursRenge[position]);

                mCardView=(CardView)v.findViewById(R.id.card_day_item);
                mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mColors[position]);


            }else {
                v =  convertView;
            }


            return v;
        }
    }
```

when i pass the array of colors from another class it not display but the array of text displayed well

```
String hoursArray[]={"7 am : 8 am" ,"8 am : 9 am","9 am : 10 am","10 am : 11 am","11 am : 12 pm","12 pm : 1 pm","1 pm : 2 pm","2 pm : 3 pm"};
        int colorsArray[]={R.color.colorOrange,R.color.colorRed,R.color.colorOrange,R.color.colorOrange,R.color.colorRed,R.color.colorOrange,R.color.colorRed,R.color.colorOrange};
        mHoursFromToAdapter=new HoursFromToAdapter(HomeActivity.this,hoursArray,colorsArray);
```

what is the problem of can not display array of colors on the cardView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setCardBackgroundColor` expects a color, not a `resId` presenting a color.

change

```
mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mColors[position])
```

with

```
mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, mColors[position]))
```

I would also move

```
mHoursRangeTxt= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_hours_from_to);
mHoursRangeTxt.setText(mHoursRenge[position]);

mCardView=(CardView)v.findViewById(R.id.card_day_item);
mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mColors[position]);
```

outside the `if else` clause and implement the holder pattern